# Foreach with multidimensional list

Tags: java

```
List< List<Integer> > arr = new ArrayList< List<Integer> >();
// filling the array
for(List<Integer> values in arr) {
   System.out.println(values[0] + values[1]);
}
```

Why doesn't it work? It displayes an error that ";" is expected, and that it cannot find the symbol. Simple for doesn't work either:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr[]; i++) {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That is not the correct syntax for the for each loop in Java. Also, you cannot use the `[index]` notation for a `List`. That syntax is reserved for arrays. Here is the proper way to iterate using for each in Java.

```
for(List<Integer> values : arr) {
   System.out.println(values.get(0) + values.get(1));
}
```

For the second half of your question, you should be iterating from `0` towards the `size()` of the `List`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
}
```

Comment: @ZouZou, Fixed. I saw the loop and didn't check the insides. :P

Comment: I delete my answer and upvote yours, since we basically have the same and I also had that access error in the first loop.